# MySQL - building a working-schedule / how to fill DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm about to build a database for a bunch of employees (around 90) to manage their working schedule more easily.  Let's say I have 3 tables which all look pretty much like this:

**date     / agent1 / agent2 / agent3 / etc.** 
01.01.2015 / Max    / Gitti  / Heinz  / etc.

One of the tables is for "work starts at 8am, ends at 2pm", 
the other is for "work starts at 2pm, ends at 9pm", 
the third is for "work starts at 3pm, ends at 9pm".

I can fill the database and manage this all by myself but that wouldn't be much of an improvement.

Is there a way to fill those tables with random names from our "employee" table while also checking for employee preferences (for example Gitti doesn't like to work on Thursday afternoons)?

I'd appreciate every single hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Find out how many spots to fill.
2. Build a function to randomly fill an array with that number of employees.

   - Make sure your function checks for preferences and doesn't add an employee to an unpreferred day.
3. Use that array to build a query for your database.
4. Run the query.

As for specifics on how to do these things, please consult php.net as well as your search engine of choice.

Comment: everything is clear to me, except of Point 3. I´ll "search.engine" it again - no luck till now... thank you!